# Consul overrides spring profiles

Tags: spring-cloud, consul

I am moving configuration file to consul. Configuration files are held in yaml on consul. This is a part of configuration yaml file (As you can see there are 2 profiles DEV, DEV2):

```
---
spring
  profiles: DEV2

environment:
  current: DEV2

urls:
  de: http://10.11.22.44
  be: http://10.11.22.44
---
spring:
  profiles: DEV

environment:
  current: DEV

urls:
  de: http://10.11.22.33
  be: http://10.11.22.33
```

The problem is that when i am running application with profile DEV2. Always urls from profile DEV are taken(Because they are lower in yaml file). Is there a way to force consul to read data from DEV2 profile ? Here is my bootstrap yaml config:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: 10.11.22.33
      port: 8500
      config:
        name: config
        acl-token: sometoken
        prefix: someprefix
        format: yaml
```

Comment: Are you missing parts of your config file? (the document separators `---`)

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add it here. Without --- in application yaml application don't even start. What i can say more is that if configuration is placed in project and i run dev2 profile with Intelij. Everything works fine

Comment: I'm not sure consul yaml files support multiple profiles documents in one file.